# is there an accepted/standard progression of ANSI terminal colors to represent (low to high) or (cold to hot)?

Tags: ansi-escape, ansi-colors

I am trying to visually enhance the output of a tool so that each shown number is also coloured based on the value (eg. green for low numbers, bright red for high ones).
similar to a heatmap but on a one-dimensional band (for now)

This is obviously doable by splitting the possible range into n bands and then selecting the colour/intensity (and maybe background) from a table

Of course, I could roll my own, but the hard part is deciding which numbers are to represent higher or lower numbers so that others easily understand the relationship
(eg, which band is more intuitive/representative?
yellow, green, blue, cyan, magenta red
or
blue, cyan, green, yellow,  magenta, red)

as orange is not doable in ANSI colours, the progression from the colour where blue->green->yellow->orange->red is not really usable.

I think this must have been done before, so is there maybe a standard or accepted convention for this (and maybe does this already exist eg a module for Python based on term colour or such)?